# How to edit a sprite gif image in eclipse

Tags: java, css, eclipse, svn, styling

I have a sprite image with .gif extention in my eclipse workspace. I want to edit the sprite image with introducing one more icon into the existing sprite image. Could any one please help me what tool should i use for editing in eclipse.
i want to edit it in eclipse because after editing i have to put it back to subversion repository so that i could get a proper revision number with status of the gif as "edited" once it is placed back into the subversion repository.

Comment: I don't think you can edit in it Eclipse, you'll need a gif editor. As to your concerns with subversion, it shouldn't make difference how you edit the value, so long as it's still in the same location within the project

Comment: I installed icon editor in eclipse but seems to be not working.

Comment: A gif isn't an icon...

Comment: check this link https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/eclipse-icons-editor/

Comment: i installed this... but not working :(

Comment: i edited the gif with the help of paint. Now the point is how to check-in this gif image sprite back to subversion repository. Can any one please help? I am asking the procedure to checkin this gif image because there would already be a gif image present in the repository and now i have to check-in this edited gif image sprite. If i will checkin my edited gif image file then two gif images with the same name will exist. SO ideally what would be procedure ?

Comment: I checked the subversion history for this particular gif image. And everytime it shows that this particular gif has been edited in all the subversion number and has not been checked in as new gif.